# Non surjectivity of $C^1$ function.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am trying to figure out how to do the following question, but i seems to not have any success.

If $f:\mathbb{R}^1\to \mathbb{R}^2$ is of class $C^1$ mapping, show that $f$ does not carry $\mathbb{R}^1$ onto $\mathbb{R}^2$.

I know that if suppose that $f$ is onto, then let $g$ be a right inverse of $f$ where $f(g(x,y))=x$.  If I differentiate $f(g(x,y))=x$, using the chain rule, i get some expression, but there is a problem because i am not sure if $g(x,y)$ is itself differentiable to begin with.

Alternatively, if i let the mapping of $f$ be written as $f(t)=(\phi_1(t), \phi_2(t))$, then the Jacobian matrix $Df(t)$ is a $2$ by $1$ matrix.  So the column rank of $Df(t)$ is $1$.  But how can i use this information to conclude that $f$ is not onto, since if $f$ were onto in the first place, won't the column rank of its Jacobian be equal to the dimension of the function's codomain.

Thanks in advance

Comment: prolly should be merged with : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/179290/there-is-no-c1-function-f-mapping-an-open-interval-in-mathbbr-onto-ope

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to prove the non-surjectivity is to show $f(\mathbb{R})$
has measure zero in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

If $|f'(x)| < M$ for $x \in [a,b]$, one can cover $f([a,b])$ by a square of length $M|b-a|$ (hint: mean value theorem). If one subdivide $[n,n+1]$ by $N$ small intervals, one get:
$$ 
\mu(f([n,n+1])) \le \sup( |f'(x)| : x \in [n,n+1] )^2 / N
$$ 
Taking $N \rightarrow +\infty$, we get $\mu(f([n,n+1])) = 0$. Being
a countable union of sets of measure zero, $f(\mathbb{R})$ itself has measure zero and hence cannot equal to $\mathbb{R}^2$.

FYI: The general form of these sort of results is known as [Morse-Sard theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sard%27s_theorem),
it is very helpful in middle of a proof where you need to pick a point outside the image of some $C^k$ map $f : M \rightarrow N$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I would also like to know is it possible to do the question without resorting to Morse-Sard Theorem.  Suppose I did not know that f(R) has measure zero in R^2 and I all i know are both the implicit and inverse function theorem.

Comment: @WillieWong

Thank you for editing my post to be more readable.  I am not very good at typing math on online forums.

Comment: @Seth: you should probably thank Thomas, not me. Cheers.

Comment: @ThomasE

Thanks for editing.  When i saw two people that had edited the post, i thought Willie Wong had did the editing first.  Anyways, thank you both.

Comment: @Seth: Sorry. I don't know other proof that is not essentially using Morse-Sard theorem in disguise.

Comment: @achillehui

That is okay if you don't know.  I am surprised that such a simple statement requires such powerful theorem to prove it.

Comment: Have you been taught "Baire category theorem"? In particular, the statement that $\mathbb{R}^2$ cannot be covered by countable union of nowhere dense set. At least for the case $f'(a) \ne 0$, it is relatively easy to see $f([a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon])$ is nowhere dense for sufficiently small $\epsilon$. Of course, "Baire Category theorem" is another very powerful tool.

Comment: @achillehui

Yes, i have been taught Baire.  I am not sure how it would help in this situation.   When i was looking at this question, all i thought about were the implicit and inverse function theorems for the case where the dimension of domain and codomain are not equal.

Comment: @Seth: stumble across this [Why isn't R2 a countable union of ranges of curves?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69915/why-isnt-mathbbr2-a-countable-union-of-ranges-of-curves) which answer this question using "Baire category theorem".